# "RUN apt-get update" did not run successfully

Tags: ubuntu, docker-compose

I have the following docker file, but every time I try to do 'docker-compose up -d' I get an exit code 100:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest as base

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install ssh
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN apt-get -y install htop
RUN apt-get -y install libpq-dev

RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get -y install cmake libopenmpi-dev python3-dev zlib1g-dev libgl1-mesa-dev

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade setuptools

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash selfplay
USER selfplay
ENV PATH="/home/selfplay/.local/bin:${PATH}"
WORKDIR /app


COPY --chown=selfplay:selfplay ./app/requirements.txt /app
RUN pip3 install -r /app/requirements.txt

COPY --chown=selfplay:selfplay ./app .

ENV PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
ENV export LANG=C.UTF-8

CMD bash
```

This is the final error message:

### 6.184 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100

Edit:

Full Error:

```
[+] Building 4.3s (6/19)                                                                                                      docker:desktop-linux
 => [app internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 715B                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [app internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [app internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [app  1/15] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                                   0.0s
 => [app internal] load build context                                                                                                         0.1s
 => => transferring context: 4.82kB                                                                                                           0.1s
 => ERROR [app  2/15] RUN apt-get update                                                                                                      4.1s
------
 > [app  2/15] RUN apt-get update:
1.006 Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
1.029 Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
1.416 Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
1.422 Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages [998 kB]
1.426 Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages
1.427   File has unexpected size (13353 != 997610). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
1.429   Hashes of expected file:
1.432    - Filesize:997610 [weak]
1.434    - SHA256:944ec4a51bef1bf7a315e2735f53d4f9111ee71aa3bfa02a8ae64bec0f03b6d2
1.437    - SHA1:8c2c342e8597ae6f010787202cab76e99f07c23e [weak]
1.437    - MD5Sum:314f44e39ac3f6ef427c8cc441052d78 [weak]
1.437   Release file created at: Tue, 26 Sep 2023 14:36:51 +0000
1.577 Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [109 kB]
1.746 Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages [17.5 MB]
1.751 Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
1.752   File has unexpected size (13331 != 17471387). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
1.752   Hashes of expected file:
1.753    - Filesize:17471387 [weak]
1.758    - SHA256:9939f6554c5cbea6607e3886634d7e393d8b0364ae0a43c2549d7191840c66c1
1.758    - SHA1:4cd575c8f284a674aa1fdb94b68c2bb67b24f89d [weak]
1.758    - MD5Sum:13f9b4229aedb1b41b8231432a0ee0d8 [weak]
1.758   Release file created at: Thu, 21 Apr 2022 17:16:08 +0000
1.977 Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [44.0 kB]
1.981 Err:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
1.981   
2.267 Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [1792 kB]
2.524 Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages [1014 kB]
2.524 Err:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
2.524   
2.850 Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 Packages [266 kB]
2.884 Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 Packages [164 kB]
2.906 Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1260 kB]
3.577 Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [1283 kB]
3.579 Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [1158 kB]
3.581 Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 Packages [1137 kB]
3.582 Err:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 Packages
3.585   
3.591 Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [49.9 kB]
3.597 Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 Packages [50.4 kB]
3.601 Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 Packages [28.1 kB]
3.848 Fetched 6660 kB in 3s (1965 kB/s)
3.848 Reading package lists...
4.095 E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/universe/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/944ec4a51bef1bf7a315e2735f53d4f9111ee71aa3bfa02a8ae64bec0f03b6d2  File has unexpected size (13353 != 997610). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
4.095    Hashes of expected file:
4.095     - Filesize:997610 [weak]
4.095     - SHA256:944ec4a51bef1bf7a315e2735f53d4f9111ee71aa3bfa02a8ae64bec0f03b6d2
4.096     - SHA1:8c2c342e8597ae6f010787202cab76e99f07c23e [weak]
4.096     - MD5Sum:314f44e39ac3f6ef427c8cc441052d78 [weak]
4.096    Release file created at: Tue, 26 Sep 2023 14:36:51 +0000
4.096 E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/c15efbf50447964d98a773cd677febcd5ab7128197972e7d6f846189847bb96e  
4.096 E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/main/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/16951e4cb4d44f56835cc8fb0cda286f6ad231275a2bd765fb4e74a11c581332  
4.096 E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/restricted/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/58a1ef71726df7f89b4516b657aee15b32bbe3593d95eefd18e4bef15752a8ba  
4.096 E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/universe/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/9939f6554c5cbea6607e3886634d7e393d8b0364ae0a43c2549d7191840c66c1  File has unexpected size (13331 != 17471387). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
4.096    Hashes of expected file:
4.096     - Filesize:17471387 [weak]
4.096     - SHA256:9939f6554c5cbea6607e3886634d7e393d8b0364ae0a43c2549d7191840c66c1
4.096     - SHA1:4cd575c8f284a674aa1fdb94b68c2bb67b24f89d [weak]
4.097     - MD5Sum:13f9b4229aedb1b41b8231432a0ee0d8 [weak]
4.097    Release file created at: Thu, 21 Apr 2022 17:16:08 +0000
4.097 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

Comment: `FROM ubuntu:bionic-20200219 as base` - why do you use such an outdated image?

Comment: I am using the code of a tutorial. I've already tried changing it to ubuntu:latest, but it didn't help

Comment: Even if this is not related to programming: maybe any of the other eror lines contains more details?

Comment: I've posted the full error message

Comment: Use a current base image or you may end up inadvertently debugging an already fixed issue.

Comment: `load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:bionic-20200219` - you are still using a completely outdated base image

Comment: What do you mean by "this"? Didn't you already use a more current version, as indicated by your comment? Then the log shouldn't mention that `ubuntu:bionic-20200219` was used

Comment: I've had the error message of the previous code in there, but it really didn't change anything, to change the version. I have now updated the error message for you

Comment: Jammy is an LTS release but it's definitely not "latest" either. Try running Docker with caching disabled.